# What is the best way for my rest api uri name to include module name that the ressource belongs to?

Tags: rest

I'm wondering what is the best way for my rest api uri name to include the  module name  that the ressource belongs  to? lets clarify this, my rest api should expose the details of Object-A and should also expose the details of Object-B, in this case i can't use the ressource name `ipAdresse:port/details` because there is two details types.
add to this that i should not use the nesting style like this `ipAdresse:port/objectA/:id/details`.

So in this case, is it better to do it the following way (include the parent ressource or module name in the url):

```
ipAdresse:port/objecta/details
```

or this way (using hyphen):

```
ipAdresse:port/objectb-details
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a small advantage to using path segments, *if* you have a family of these documents that want to link to each other

```
/objecta/details
/objecta/comments
/objecta/pricing
```

These resources can all reference each other using dot segments (ex: ../comments), which means that you don't have to specify the "objecta" part in the links.  In other words, you could move the whole family of identifiers to a different location in your hierarchy, and relative resolution would just work.

```
/objectb-details
/objectb-comments
/objectb-pricing
```

Each of these paths is a single segment, so dot segments remove the entire path, which you would have to replace (ex: ../objectb-comment), and if you decide to replace the objectb prefix with something else, you also need to update all of the links.

In effect, using `/` gives you a little bit of future proofing.

---

That said, if the hyphen-minus is part of the name of the thing, then leave it in the identifier.

```
/objective-c/comments
```

If you bring one of these to me in a code review, I'm going to think you've lost the plot:

```
/objective/c/comments
/objective-c-comments
```

But of course they will work just as well (the machines don't care) as long as the identifiers match the syntax described by RFC 3986.